# OpenAPI reference a property of objects in an array of objects

Tags: yaml, openapi

I have a question about OpenAPI specification in Yaml. I'm willing to make an array of ids that has the id of each object that is in another array of objects. For Example:

```
components:
  schemas:
    Author:
          type: object
          required:
            - id
            - name
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            name:
              type: string
            Books:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Books/items/properties/id' # the reference is not correct.
    Books:
            type: array
            items:
                type: object
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Book'
    Book:
        type: object
          required:
            - id
            - title
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
```

how can i specify it correctly?

Comment: Do you mean how to indicate the _logical relation_ between the schemas? I.e. indicate that StringsArray is an array of User ids specifically and not just random ids?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I noticed that I have done a mistake in defining the schemas and I corrected it and I wrote a better example. I'm willing to specify the the logical relation between the schemas. In the new example I have an author and I would like to have all the ids of his books in an array that is a property in the schema author.